# What is the meaning of pig exit codes?

Tags: apache-pig

Pig exists with exit code **7** after printing these 3 lines:

```
2014-07-16 21:57:37,271 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.11.0-cdh4.6.0 (rexported) compiled Feb 26 2014, 03:01:22
2014-07-16 21:57:37,272 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: ..../pig_1405562257268.log
2014-07-16 21:57:37,627 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /home/sam/.pigbootup not found
```

what does this mean?

- The `INFO` messages are normal
- The only unusual bit is the exit code (7, see above)
- The `pig_*.log` file does *not* exist

Is this documented somewhere?

EDIT: the problem was eliminated when I removed the semicolon from the end of the `%declare` line.
go figure...

Comment: @verbose-mode: exit code is 7

Comment: Did you check the log file?

Comment: @RajnishG: what log? `pig_1405562257268.log` does not exist

Comment: It should be in your logs directory like for me any pig logs are stored in pig/logs/pig_623734717264.log. If its not there then try Job Browser or JobTracker Web UI to find the real error behind Pig exiting with a return code of 7.

Comment: There is no log. There is no hadoop job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may take a look at the return codes in the [source code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/PigRunner.java).
The book [Programming Pig](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449302645) also contains a list of their meaning in chapter two.
I copy [them](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch02.html#return_codes) here for reference:

```
0   Success      
1   Retriable failure    
2   Failure      
3   Partial failure - Used with multiquery; see “Nonlinear Data Flows”
4   Illegal arguments passed to Pig      
5   IOException thrown - Would usually be thrown by a UDF
6   PigException thrown - Usually means a Python UDF raised an exception
7   ParseException thrown (can happen after parsing if variable substitution
    is being done)   
8   Throwable thrown (an unexpected exception)
```